# changing layout to include a static block

Tags: magento1.6.2

Can anyone help me change this please?

```
<trade_customer_logged_in>
<reference name="product.info.tabs">
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" 
<alias>delivery_info</alias><title>Delivery Information</title> 
<block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block> 
<template>catalog/product/view/delivery-info.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</trade_customer_logged_in>
```

So instead of it pulling in delivery-info.phtml I want it to pull in a static block I have created with the ID 'delivery-info'

Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work:

    <trade_customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">       
    <block type="cms/block" name="delivery-info" before="-">
    <action method="setBlockId">
    <block_id>delivery-info</block_id></action>
    </block>
    </reference>
    </trade_customer_logged_in>

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
    <trade_customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="product.info.tab">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="module.data" as="delivery" template="catalog/product/view/delivery-info.phtml">
                <action method="addTab"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Delivery Information</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </trade_customer_logged_in>
```

**hope its work for you**